# Can I have two stored procs running on the same message queue for SQL Server Service Broker?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, message-queue, service-broker

I have a queue that fills up with multiple types of messages and I want to have two stored procedures running on that same queue, one for each message type.

I don't want one that checks for multiple types.

The issue is, I can't see how to define two in the queue definition:

```
CREATE QUEUE MyQueue  WITH ACTIVATION
(
    STATUS = ON,
    -- How have two?
    PROCEDURE_NAME = [my_listener_proc],
    MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 4,
    EXECUTE AS SELF
)
GO
```

Comment: Short answer: No. Either create separate queues or create a stored procedure to call one of the other two based on message type

Answer (score 0):

A comment above has the right of it - you only get one activation procedure. But you can put logic in that proc to do other things based on the message type. Here's a slightly redacted version of one that I have in production:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [repl].[myActivation]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @message_type nvarchar(256),
        @message XML,
        @rc INT,
        @queuing_order BIGINT;
    DECLARE @messages TABLE (
        [message_type] sysname, 
        [message] XML
    );
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WHILE(1=1)
    BEGIN

        WAITFOR(
            RECEIVE TOP (1000)
                [message_type_name],
                CAST([message_body] AS XML)
            FROM [repl].[myQueue]
            INTO @messages
        ), TIMEOUT 5000;

        IF (@@rowCount = 0)
            BREAK;
        ELSE
        BEGIN

            DECLARE [messages] CURSOR FAST_FORWARD LOCAL
            FOR
            SELECT [message], [message_type]
            FROM @messages;

            OPEN [messages];
            WHILE(1=1)
            BEGIN
                FETCH NEXT FROM [messages] 
                INTO @message, @message_type;
                IF (@@fetch_Status <> 0)
                    BREAK;

                BEGIN TRY

                    IF (@message_type = 'A')
                    BEGIN
                        EXEC @rc = [repl].[ProcessAMessage] 
                            @message = @message;
                    END
                    ELSE IF (@message_type = 'B')
                    BEGIN
                        EXEC @rc = [repl].[ProcessBMessage]
                            @message = @message;
                    END 

                    IF (@rc <> 0)
                    BEGIN
                        INSERT INTO [repl].[DeadLetters]
                                ( [Payload], [MessageType] )
                        VALUES  ( @message, @message_type );
                    END
                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                    INSERT INTO [repl].[DeadLetters]
                            ( [Payload], [MessageType] )
                    VALUES  ( @message, @message_type );
                END CATCH
            END
            CLOSE [messages];
            DEALLOCATE [messages];

            DELETE @messages;
        END
    END
END
GO
```

There's a fair bit going on there (aside from routing to different procs based on the message type) including:

- Receiving multiple messages at a time so as not to lock the conversation too often
- Taking a couple of steps to *make sure* that the activation procedure doesn't roll back/error out. Poison messages can wreck your day.

I don't use transactions in mine because there's another process that ensures that the effects of the message are applied. So, it doesn't matter much if any given message makes it (as the fact that it doesn't will be detected relatively quickly).